# Let $f(x)$ be a function satisfying $f'(x)>0, f''(x)>0 \;\forall\; x\in (0,1)$ and $f(0)=0, f(1)=1$, then which of the following options is/are true?

Tags: integration, functions, derivatives, inverse

Let $f(x)$ be a function satisfying $f'(x)>0, f''(x)>0 \;\forall\; x\in (0,1)$ and $f(0)=0, f(1)=1$, then which of the following options is/are true?

(A) $f\bigg(\dfrac{1}{2}\bigg)f\bigg(\dfrac{1}{3}\bigg)<1$

(B) $f^{-1}\bigg(\dfrac{1}{2}\bigg)f^{-1}\bigg(\dfrac{1}{3}\bigg)>1$

(C) $f\bigg(\dfrac{1}{3}\bigg)f^{-1}\bigg(\dfrac{1}{3}\bigg)<\dfrac{1}{3}$

(D) $f\bigg(\dfrac{1}{2}\bigg)f^{-1}\bigg(\dfrac{1}{2}\bigg)>\dfrac{1}{2}$

**My Approach:**

Since graph is concave upword so i got $f(x)<x$ after drawing graph between $(0,1)$

and since $f^{-1}(x)$ will be mirror image in line $y=x,\;$ so $f^{-1}(x)>x$

So I obtained the option (A) i.e.,

$f\bigg(\dfrac{1}{2}\bigg)f\bigg(\dfrac{1}{3}\bigg)<1\;$ because $\;f\bigg(\dfrac{1}{2}\bigg)<\dfrac{1}{2}\;$ and $\;f\bigg(\dfrac{1}{3}\bigg)<\dfrac{1}{3}\;$

**My Doubts**

(i) Is my approach correct?

(ii) How to obtain other options?

Comment: Option (C) is true also.

Comment: @Jean-ArmandMoroni But How?

Comment: Because, as you stated, $\forall x \in (0,1), f(x)<x$. So $f(\frac 1 3) < \frac 1 3$. And $f^{-1}(\frac 1 3) <1$ by definition of $f$. Then, as both are positive, you can multiply the inequalities.

Comment: By the way, you should prove that in $(0,1), f(x)<x$. Also it is surprising that the exercise assumes $f^{-1}$ is well defined, without asking for a proof.

Comment: @Jean-ArmandMoroni What about other options?